# Hibernate and maps with enums

Tags: java, hibernate

I have map in my entity:

```
private Map<String, MyEnum> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

where `MyEnum` is enum.
How to correctly annotate this in hibernate? I would like to have one table (and of course as this is one to many, one additional table that stores foreign keys):

```
+-----+--------+--------+
| key | string | MyEnum |
+-----+--------+--------+
|   1 | banana | PERU   |
|   2 | orange | BRAZIL |
+-----+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@ElementCollection
private Map<String, MyEnum> names = new HashMap<>();
```

Result:

FKID,   ENUM(As String) ,   STRING